# How to find feedback coefficient \$\beta\$ of this current-voltage feedback circuit?

Tags: feedback

Here is the circuit from [YouTube](https://youtu.be/L-fihvU3VC8?list=PLc7Gz02Znph-c2-ssFpRrzYwbzplXfXUT&t=2314):

[image]

In order to determine the feedback, we have to break the loop at the gate of M1.

Assume A is \$\infty\$, so \$V_{GS}\$ of M1 is 0. As we know the \$V_S\$ of M1 is grounded, we have \$V_S = V_G = 0\$. And that's why the gate of M1 is grounded.

[image]

$$\frac{V_{out}} {I_{in}} = R_2 \parallel R_3$$

The following is how I break the loop and add test voltage.

[image]

$$Loop \hspace{1mm} Gain  = L = \frac{V_F} {V_t} = g_{m1} \bigr(R_3 \parallel (R_1 + R_2)\bigr) \frac{R_1} {R_1 + R_2}$$

Comment: Why do you call it a **current-voltage feedback circuit**? It's a potential divider and the attenuation it provides is the feedback factor.

Comment: @Andyaka What's the \$\beta\$ according to you?

Comment: \$\dfrac{R_1}{R_1+R_2}\$ and, you don't need to break any loops to see this.

Comment: @Andyaka Nope, check https://youtu.be/L-fihvU3VC8?list=PLc7Gz02Znph-c2-ssFpRrzYwbzplXfXUT&t=2452

Comment: Sorry but youtube is not a technical authority that can be trusted. There are many sources that agree with me: https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=2e0a38931ff166af&rlz=1C1_____en-gbGB1078GB1079&sxsrf=ACQVn09oku885gRJdA3Ap1HBTGkuovFCKg:1711286165443&q=amplifier+feedback+coefficient&tbm=isch&source=lnms&prmd=ivnbmtz&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi28v_f_YyFAxV7QkEAHbMiBr0Q0pQJegQICRAB&biw=1680&bih=901&dpr=1#imgrc=PTe5_wHtMSa1AM

Comment: @kile You should include M1 in the feedback network.

Comment: @internet What does the feedback network look like?

Comment: @internet Is this feedback network  the same as https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kc1zL.png

Comment: @kile yes because they're the same circuit

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because academic questions need an attempt at a solution

Comment: @VoltageSpike I have tried to solve this with my way. But they said it's not correct.
The following is what I have tried.


Assume A is \$\infty\$, so \$V_{GS}\$ of M1 is 0. As we know the \$V_S\$ of M1 is grounded, we have \$V_S = V_G = 0\$. And that's why the gate of M1 is grounded.

Comment: @VoltageSpike See my updates on my question

Comment: @internet Do I add my test voltage correctly? 
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/707531/how-can-i-calculate-loop-gain-when-considering-loading-effect-in-voltage-current

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The feedback network includes R1, R2, and the transistor M1.
The feedback factor \$\beta\$ is calculated as follows:

\$\beta = \frac{i_{fb}}{V_{out}} = g_{m1}\cdot\frac{R1}{R1 + R2}\$

[image]

Comment: I think the trickiest thing is how to find the feedback network. Can you explain how you find this feedback network?

Comment: @kile - the above consideration is correct (see my detailed answer).

Comment: @kile If you compare the circuit with this diagram [here](https://www.eeeguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/11/Voltage-Shunt-Feedback-Amplifier-Circuit-12.jpg), you can identify different parts of the feedback network. Also, check the LvW answer.

Comment: @internet I draw a a schematic on how I break the loop. Can you see my updates on the question? Do I break the loop correctly?

Comment: @kile Yes, you can break the loop like that but you make a mistake in your calculate of LG.

Comment: @internet Do we have to consider loading effect?

Comment: @kile no, you don't need to add loading effect in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Here comes my explanation of the shown circuit:

**1.)** The input of the amplifier (common gate configuration with a current input) is the source node of M2.

**2.)** Therefore, the feedback signal (in form of a current) is superimposed at this node with the signal current. That means: Transistor **M1 is part of the feedback path**. It is its purpose to convert the feedback voltage (at the gate of M1) into a current.

**3.)** Opening the feedback loop at the gate of M1 and injecting a test voltage Vt,in, we get the loop gain expression:

**Loop gain LG=Vt,out/Vt,in** with

**id1=gm1*Vt,in**  and

**Vt,out=[R1/(R1+R2)] * id2 * R3||(R1+R2)**

**Loop gain** **LG=Vt,out/Vt,in=[R1/(R1+R2)] * (id2/id1) * gm1 * R3||(R1+R2)**

Because of **id2=id1** we can simplify:

**LG=[R1/(R1+R2)] * gm1 * R3||(R1+R2)**

The gain of the **open loop** is

**Aol=Vout/i,in=R3||(R1+R2)****

Therefore the feedback "factor" is beta=LG/Aol:

**beta=[R1/(R1+R2)] * gm1**.

Comment: I draw a a schematic on how I break the loop. Can you see my updates on the question?

Comment: @kile - Yes, and what is the question?

Comment: is the schematic the same as your description?