# How can I calculate loop gain when considering loading effect in voltage-current feedback?

Tags: feedback

This is the schematic.

[image]

According to the figure from 8.5 in [*Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit*](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), page 277:

[image]

Here we break the loop and add test voltage.

It looks like impossible to find the relationship between \$V_T\$ and \$V_F\$.
So the loop gain \$L\$ is undetermined.

[image]

Comment: The directions you are using are for a voltage amplifier. Your actual amplifier is current input with voltage output, that makes it it transimpedance amplifier.  Why don't you see if your book mentions that sort of amplifier, and how to deal with it.

Comment: @TimWescott I am unable to find any hints. Could you give me more hints? Where am I wrong?

Comment: @kile This is not hard. But start by asking yourself "*What happens to a tiny change of current at the input?"* Don't include the feedback effect. Ignore that part. Where does a tiny current change go? How does it affect things? Qualitative hand waving is fine. But walk yourself through that thought for a moment. Start there.

Comment: @periblepsis Is my diagram for adding the test circuit correct?

Comment: @kile I would start by answering my question about what happens with a tiny current change. I'm not considering your added diagram, for now. Would instead like to hear how you think about the tiny current change, first.

Comment: @kile I don't know why you want to break the loop at that point. Second, it's weird that you put the test signal at the drain of the MOS transistor (backward signal flow).

Comment: @internet Where should I break the loop and add the test voltage?